# How to apply Genetic algorithm in budget allocation for libraries

Tags: php, mysql, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, recommendation-engine

I have a master project where I should develop a web based system to allocate budget to buy next year books in different subjects for an academic library

The allocation should be based on the data mining of the library circulation database (Data base that contains each borrowing transaction)'
'

The main rule is (The more a department of a faculty in the university makes use of books related to its subject, the more budget this subject should be allocated for the next year)

The system will be developed using PHP, HTML and Mysql as database

I was advised by my supervisor to use Genetic Algorithm (GA) technique in the data mining

My problem is that I don't know how can I map the GA process to the budget allocation process

I read a lot of papers on that subject the only one about the almost the same subject was in Persian - Lucky me :) - and other papers about the using data mining in budget allocation did not explain in depth the mapping between the budget allocation elements and the data mining techniques

What I think I need is to know how to map the budget allocation problem to GA process:

1. what will be the genes?
2. what will be the chromosomes?
3. how will the matting be done?
   I just need some clarifications on the basic level

Answer (score 1):

These combinations do not make sense.

The objective (more use = more allocation) can be solved using a single equation. There is no leeway to use any data mining here, or genetic algorithm.

Also the tools (php, html, mysql) is about the most useless combination for this? Don't use any of them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question
It is the main rule to allocate more money for departments that use more, but it is not the only rule, there will be survey result that should be taken to consideration, library requirements, Higher education committee regulations and more few elements that may effect the budget allocation decision making 
Te main reason for using data mining is that the amount of data produced by the library circulation system is huge and divided in to many tables
So under these conditions do you have an idea how to map it to GA or any other data mining technique?

Comment: Data mining does not guarantee scalability. On contrary, the methods are often hard to scale. The larger your data. the simpler your approach. And I still don't see any data mining potential here.

Comment: What is your training data? What is your evaluation? Your optimization objective *function*?